# not a valid textual representation, problem: UUID has to be represented by the standard

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, uuid

What is the reason for not valid UUID not being processed with the exception below?

```
WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not construct instance of java.util.UUID from String value 'a98c543-22de-4330-2995-ff81889aa412': not a valid textual representation, problem: UUID has to be represented by the standard 36-char representation; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.UUID from String value 'a98c543-22de-4330-2995-ff81889aa412': not a valid textual representation, problem: UUID has to be represented by the standard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason was in UUID generator, it was generating

`a98c543` as the first block having 7 digits instead of 8, like they were missing leading zeroes